# Was the 90's Flash TV Show set in the same universe as Tim Burton's Batman?

Tags: dc, tv, dc-extended-universe, the-flash, the-flash-1990

Apart from being a very few years apart, I remember the show had certain aesthetical choices like Danny Elfman's music, the latex-neckless muscled suit design and a dark-cartoonish tone that related to the first two Batman movies.

I know that in the 90's a *universe* was not a concept frequently applied to movies, as we do today in our film sagas. Anyways, I can't help but thinking that, along with this series, if the [infamous Tim Burton's aborted Superman movie](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Lives) and the [Catwoman spinoff](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/the_tim_burtonmichelle_pf) would've been made, DC would have had some kind of primitive version of the MCU, where creative staff, stories and actors were somewhat connected... maybe a complete failure in that decade, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [The Burton-verse](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Burtonverse) only encompasses the two Burton movies, plus the two Joel Schumacker movies

- Batman (1989 Movie)
- Batman Returns (Movie)
- Batman Forever (Movie)
- Batman and Robin (Movie)

Only Superman ever gets mentioned in any of the movies, and only in passing. The Flash was an even smaller hero back then than he is now. I don't think anyone mentions him in passing.

Comment: So, the only real connection was Danny elfman?

Comment: The closest Flash comes to that was in [Superman:TAS episode "Speed Demons"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Superman:_The_Animated_Series_episodes) in 1997. Since Batman:TAS was created as a result of the success of the Burtonverse (although not part of it), and Superman:TAS was created because of that success, I suppose you could consider that a bank shot.

Comment: @Machavity - Noting of course that, at the time, BTAS was considered by many to be the best current version of Batman (over both the first Burton movie, and the current comics). Not arguing *your* point, of course - the movie came first, and probably did lead to the nod to start the cartoon.